# Regex - Find text between specific characters containing other specific text

Tags: regex

Let's say I have the following string:

*{sometext1Asometext2};{sometext3Bsometext4};{sometext5Csometext6}*

I want to match this:

*{sometext3Bsometext4}*

So the text between brackets, but not all matches, only the one containing B.

On the internet I can only find examples of matching everything between 2 characters, not only text containing some specific string inside.

The values of 'sometext' are unknown.

Comment: `{[^}]*B[^}]*}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
{[^}B]*B[^}]*}
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6JScbD/2)

OR

```
{(?=[^}]*B)[^}]*}
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6JScbD/3)

**Explanation(1st regex):**

- `{` - matches `{`
- `[^}B]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is neither a `}` nor `B`
- `B` - matches `B`
- `[^}]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a `}`
- `}` - matches `}`

Comment: thanks! i literally tried dozens of expressions and none worked!